# Mix Shimano Deore derailleurs with Microshift shifter for Shimano

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifter, derailleur-rear, shifting

I have Shimano Deore derailleurs 3x8 and I am thinking about upgrading my system with a combined shifter/brake system, such as Microshift's SB-R483. Microshift themeselves states that this system is only compatible with Shimano Claris 8 speed 2403,2303,3303 derailleur system.

However, half ignoring their statement, could it be possible to use the SB-R483-system for a Shimano Deore derailleur? Doesn't Shimano have an internal standard for the derailleur system so that a Shimano compatible 3x8 shifter fits any Shimano 3x8 derailleur system. Any experience or superb technical knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

The stumbling block is that while Shimano mountain and road rear derailers used the same actuation ratio and were fully cross-compatible until the start of 10spd mountain, the front derailers have always used a different cable pull. So if you have a mountain FD as well, you'll probably find it's impossible to get the front shifting set up for no chain rub anywhere, and shifting performance won't be very good. There are many questions here that explore options in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Shimano Deore rear derailleur and use it with 2303 shifters. The bike came this way from the factory from a reputable bike manufacturer, so they were probably all designed to be compatible. My Deore M591 rear derailleur works flawlessly with my shifters.

The front derailleur on my bike is a Shimano 2303 so I can't say for certain if the Microshift shifters would work with the front derailleur if you have a Deore front derailleur. However, I'm reasonable certain that 8 speed is 8 speed and would probably work fine.